Prove that Grassmannian is closed submanifold under Plücker embedding.
My question: Is it possible to prove that the Grassmannian $\mathbf{G}(k,V)$ is a closed (embedded) submanifold of $P(\bigwedge^kV)$, using the following characterization of the image? Here $V=\mathbb{R}^n$.
If not, can you provide a proof that uses minimal understanding of a differential manifold?
Lemma. If $0\neq\omega\in\bigwedge^k{V}$, let $W:=\{v\in V:v\wedge \omega=0\}$, then $\dim W\leq k$, and $\omega$ is in the image of the Plücker embedding if and only if $\dim W=k$.
I'm looking for this because it is claimed possible in a book, and the definition of a closed submanifold also seems 'elementary'. I know a way to construct charts on the Grassmannian explicitly, and the Plücker relations, but this result doesn't seem to follow.
Thanks in advance!

It does follow from the Plücker relations. The preimage of a closet set ($0$) under a continuous map is closed.
